# VB.net runtime query wont work

Tags: vb.net

For some reason this query don't run, can anyone tell me if i have it layed out correct

```
Dim Command As New OleDbCommand(UPDATE Transaction SET T_outwgt = '123' WHERE T_transactionno ='20160002', 
                                DBConnection)
```

Comment: `can anyone tell me if i have it layed out correct ` short answer **no you don't**... Also this question lacks details please update so we can help you.

Comment: Here not enough information about problem you have. Give us more your code, error exception etc

Comment: Error 5 Comma, ')', or a valid expression continuation expected.

Comment: You command needs to be enclosed in`""`... That should fix that error. Also update your question not a comment...

Comment: Also that should not even compile its a syntax error. You said it don't run does that mean compile?

Comment: No it does not, sorry thats what i ment to say

Comment: ("UPDATE Transaction SET T_outwgt = '123' WHERE T_transactionno =" & "20160002" & "'", DBConnection)

Comment: That gives me the error, "Syntax error in UPDATE Statement.